# python: replace every 18th character of every nth line in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, bigdata, text-files

Because of the way the dataset I have is formatted, each hourly timestamp is written as 18 0 instead of 1800 (for example), and the extra space instead of a zero is messing up the way that Excel is converting the dataset from a TAB file to a CSV. There are >  600,000 lines, and this happens every 4th line.

**[see snapshot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awM33.jpg)**

I'm reading the text file in, reading each line, and then trying to replace the 18th character of every 4th line (the wretched space) with a 0

I think I am incorrectly understanding how to make each line a string, and also not sure how to correct the line and then re-save it into the file that will be ready to convert to a CSV

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable, and so they do not support item or slice assigment. You'll have to build a new string using i.e. `someString[:18] + 'a' + someString[19:]` or some other suitable approach, then storing it in the file again!.